# swapping between songs with a button

Tags: javascript, html, button, src

I'm trying to swap between 2 songs with a button click. I can successfully swap the song once just by changing the src but when I use and if else statement the controls "flicker", which means I must have a bug inside my if else statement.

HTML

```
<div id = "audioplayer">
    <p id="songname">Listen to  Sisyphus by Have A Nice Life</p>
    <audio id = "song"
        controls
        src="Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp3">
        Your browser does not support the
        <code>audio</code> element.
    </audio>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to change songs</button>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById("song").src === "Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp3") {

        document.getElementById("songname").innerHTML = "listening to track03.mp3";
        document.getElementById("song").src = "test.mp3";
    }

    else{

    document.getElementById("songname").innerHTML = "Listen to Sisyphus by Have A Nice Life";
    document.getElementById("song").src = "Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp3";



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can set the `.src` with a relative path (like to `"Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp"`), accessing the `.src` property will give you the *full* path:

```js
const song = document.getElementById("song");
song.src = "test.mp3";
console.log(song.src);
```

```html
<audio id="song" controls src="Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp3"></audio>
```

So, you just need to replace your tests with the full path instead, for example:

```
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("song").src === "https://example.com/Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp3") {
    // ...
```

Live snippet (working HTML, but without the actual sounds):

```js
function myFunction() {
  const song = document.getElementById("song");
  const songname = document.getElementById("songname");
  if (song.src === "https://stacksnippets.net/Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp3") {
    songname.innerHTML = "listening to track03.mp3";
    song.src = "test.mp3";
  } else {
    songname.innerHTML = "Listen to Sisyphus by Have A Nice Life";
    song.src = "Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp3";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="audioplayer">
  <p id="songname">Listen to Sisyphus by Have A Nice Life</p>
  <audio id="song" controls src="Untitled/10%20Sisyphus.mp3">
                Your browser does not support the
                <code>audio</code> element.
            </audio>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to change songs</button>
```

Comment: after getting the full path i got it to swap once again, but once pressing the button again it stays put at the test.mp3, strange

Comment: Works just fine, see live snippet

Comment: got it! thanks so much, its been bugging be for awhile now.

cheers